# Automating deletion of mail in mutt

Tags: mutt

How can I delete a group of mails from inbox, say that has been received on a particular date, via cmd line in mutt?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which mail server are you using on which OS?

Comment: I am not sure about the mail server but I use UNIX.

Answer (score 0):

First enter `delete-pattern` mode by pressing Shift-D. Now you can use a [date pattern](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-4.html#ss4.2) to select the mails you want to delete (in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, month and year are optional):

```
~d 01/06/2015-01/08/2015
```

Comment: Can I do this in command line itself i.e before I even enter into the mail box by typing in 'mutt'?